# How can I serve nested projects in Nginx

Tags: regex, git, laravel, nginx, lumen

I have a Lumen api project with multiple git tags for api versioning. So I have to deploy multiple checkouts of the project.

The folder structure on the server looks like this:

```
var
   www
     api-staging
       master
         v1
           public
             index.php
           ...
         v2
           public
             index.php
           ...
         lastest
            public
              index.php
            ...
         ...
```

Now I'd like to serve the projects via nginx so that the url looks something like this.

http://BRANCH.domain.tld/VERSION/ eg. http://master.domain.tld/lastest/

I have tried a lot with regexp, but nothing really worked. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Just set up the different virtual hosts for each folder structure.

Comment: @Suraj I would like to prevent this. Also, with the amount of branches this will not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to capture the `BRANCH` using a regular expression `server_name` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more.

The root is constructed by appending `/public` to the captured `VERSION`, which requires a regular expression `location` and an `alias` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.

For example:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name  ~^(?<branch>.+)\.domain\.tld$;

    location ~ ^/(?<version>[^/]+)/(?<name>.*)$ {

        alias /var/www/api-staging/$branch$version/public/$name;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ $version/index.php last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do this if the version number is passed via request header instead of the server url domain?

Comment: Definitely. The value of a request header is available through the `$http_` family of variables. The appropriate variable can be used within the `alias` statement.